# What conditions are there for me to access my router using it's public IP?

Tags: router, isp

I've noticed that I can only access a router's login page when my current IP is in the same block as the router's IP.

The IP's my ISP give my router are always within certain ranges, for example 12.34.64.0-12.34.127.255 ( 12.34.64.0/18 ). When i try to connect to my router's login page from a source IP outside this range, my requests are dropped.

An nmap scan of the router's public IP shows all ports are filtered. But when i try again from a source IP within that range, port 80 is open and my router's login can be accessed.

Does this happen at ISP level or is it a feature of my router? How can i circumvent it?

PS: Port forwarding works fine even when outside the block, just access to the router's login(and ssh) is blocked.
(Repost from NESO)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I edited the question a bit to explain. The post you provided does help a bit, but I'm not sure if it's true here as well. I'll look into it and post updates here. Thanks

Comment: For security reasons your router will not allow this. Too many hackers out there. Some routers will allow you to make a change in the configuration(look for the word "management") to allow this, This is disabled by default, and for security reasons it is not considered very smart to enable it..